# which kind of data are store If i terminate the call in sim800?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-ide, communication, gsm

I'm working in SIM800 for DTMF based project.

I want to know which kind of data are stored in the buffer during termination of call in SIM800.

How to find if call was disconnected in SIM800?

Also please suggest some AT-COMMAND tester software and DTMF codes for my reference.